# What am I doing wrong with async/await?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I'm working on creating an application that basically plays a game for me. It forms raids, joins the raids, and then launches the raid. I'm trying to do this all asynchronously.

Some background: FormRaidAsync, JoinRaidAsync, and LaunchRaidAsync all make web requests. The methods themselves are set up to be asynchronous as well, but when I run the program, it's only joining about 2-3 accounts/second.

Am I doing something wrong, or does async/await not necessarily run each request on a new thread? If that's the case, how can I tweak this code to join the accounts at a rate closer to 10/second? Will I have to use some other form of multi-threading to make more requests at once?

Thanks everyone. Let me know if there's more detail needed.

```
public async Task<string> StartRaidAsync()
{
    string raid_id = String.Empty;

    try
    {
        raid_id = await this.Helper.FormRaidAsync(this.TargetRaid.Id, this.Former.Id, this.TargetRaid.IsBossRaid).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine("Formed raid with {0}.", this.Former.Name);

        List<Task> joinTasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var joiner in this.Joiners)
        {
            try
            {
                joinTasks.Add(this.Helper.JoinRaidAsync(raid_id, joiner.Id));
            }
            catch (Exception)   // Not sure which exceptions to catch yet.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error joining {0}. Skipped.", joiner.Name);
            }
        }

        Task.WaitAll(joinTasks.ToArray());

        await this.Helper.LaunchRaidAsync(raid_id, this.Former.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} launched raid.", this.Former.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception)   // Not sure which exceptions to catch yet.
    {
        return "ERROR";
    }

    return raid_id;
}
```

Inside JoinRaidAsync:

```
public async Task JoinRaidAsync(string raid_id, string suid)
{
    var postUrl = "some url";
    var postData = "some data";

    await this.Socket.PostAsync(postUrl, postData).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine("Joined {0}.", suid);
}
```

Inside Socket.PostAsync:

```
public async Task<string> PostAsync(string url, string postData)
{
    return await SendRequestAsync(url, postData).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Inside SendRequestAsync:

```
protected virtual async Task<string> SendRequestAsync(string url, string postData)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = this.CreateRequest(url);

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(postData))
            {
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
                var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    await writer.WriteAsync(postData).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await writer.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)))
            {
                string responseString = String.Empty;

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

                return responseString;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: When you are "Not sure which exceptions to catch yet" **do not catch the exception**.  Let it bubble up.  If you ultimately find an exception you do not want to bubble up, you now know precisely which exception to catch.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what problem are you having.

Answer (score 5):

> Am I doing something wrong, or does async/await not necessarily run each request on a new thread?

`async`/`await` does not create new threads.

> If that's the case, how can I tweak this code to join the accounts at a rate closer to 10/second?

Asynchronous code can do multiple requests at once. The speed of those requests, of course, is determined by the speed of the web service calls.

The only thing I see wrong in the code right now is that it is mixing blocking and asynchronous code. Replace:

```
Task.WaitAll(joinTasks.ToArray());
```

with:

```
await Task.WhenAll(joinTasks.ToArray());
```

If you're still seeing problems, it's likely due to your web services or other supporting code (such as the code within `JoinRaidAsync`).

Comment: Thanks for replying Stephen. I've been reading a lot of your blog posts regarding async and await. I'm just dipping my toes in it and trying to get a grasp for how it all works. I've updated my main question to include the flow up to the actual web request. If you see anything immediately wrong, please let me know.